# Search and replace within Google Site

Tags: google-classic-sites

How do I search and replace HTML code on all pages of a Google Sites website? I have many pages.

Specifically, I want to insert the new Google Analytics Universal code and delete the old code on all pages of my Google Sites website.

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sites/